# Display Random Posts with thumbnail instead of just a title of the post

Tags: post-thumbnails

This code works really well. It displays the title of the post randomly with permalink but my objective is to display the thumbnail and/or featured image instead.

Any help would be appreciated.[image]

```
<?php function wpb_rand_posts() { 
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby'   => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 5, 


    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $string = '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        $string .= '<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() .' </a></li>';

        }
        $string .= '</ul>';

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
    $string .= 'no posts found';
    }
    return $string; 
} 
add_shortcode('random-posts','wpb_rand_posts');
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the post thumbnail HTML using the function `get_the_post_thumbnail()`, so you just need to replace `get_the_title()` with that function:

```
$string .= '<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'. get_the_post_thumbnail() .' </a></li>';
```

By default the image will be the size [defined by your theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_post_thumbnail_size/), but you use any of the [other available sizes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Thumbnail_Sizes) by passing the size name as the 2nd argument of the function:

```
$string .= '<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'. get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'large' ) .' </a></li>';
```

Comment: Thanks jacob. Any idea i can make the post parallel instead of vertical?

Comment: Wouldn't have anything to do with the shortcode code. Not really. You'd just need to use CSS to lay the posts out. This isn't really the place for general CSS questions though. stackoverflow.com would be more appropriate, but I'm sure somebody's already asked. If you search the web you'll find hundreds of articles on layout out content horizontally or in columns.

Comment: Thanks mate. Appreciate your help though:)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
$string .= '<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() .' </a></li>';
```

WITH

```
$string .= '<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'. get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail' ) .' </a></li>';
```

**get_the_post_thumbnail** function is showing the featured image at front end.

Here is the full code:

```
<?php 

function wpb_rand_posts() { 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'orderby'   => 'rand',
        'posts_per_page' => 5
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $string = '<ul class="wpb-rand-posts">';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            $string .= '<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'. get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail' ) .' </a></li>';
        }

        $string .= '</ul>';

        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        $string .= 'no posts found';
    }

    return $string; 
} 
add_shortcode('random-posts','wpb_rand_posts');
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');  

?>
```

I added the CSS class name into the UL tag.

You will add this CSS into your **style.css** file

```
ul.wpb-rand-posts {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wpb-rand-posts li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: calc( ( 100% - 40px ) / 5 );
}

.wpb-rand-posts li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: works like a charm! However, post lines up instead of row. Any idea?

Comment: or was it even possible?

Comment: I am not sure about your HTML markup and css class name. You can try like this

`.your-unique-css-classname li {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 10px;
}`

Comment: I'm thinking maybe the layout of the post is just within this part. Not really an expert coder, so i would really appreciate your help here.   


 $string = '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        
        $string .= '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'. get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail' ) .' </a>';
        
        
        }
      $string .= '</ul>';

Comment: Ok. I shall update above code soon. So you can test once.

Comment: Thanks paul for your patience.. I think i was able to make it.

added this code on the $string.
<div style="float: left; margin: 0px 0px 15px 15px;" width="100">
Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Nice you got this yourself. But I updated my answer above. You can see once.

Comment: Did try it paul if it will look better but to no good. Post still is vertical.

Comment: I see. May be CSS is conflicting with global once